# ISO C++ forbids declaration of post with no type

Tags: c++, struct

I've seen a couple similar questions on here, but I can't seem to match any of their problems to my program.  Can someone help me identify why it won't let me declare my struct in my .h file?

The error I am getting is ISO forbids declaration of 'post' with no type.

Thanks in advance, I appreciate you having taken a look at my file.

```
#include <iostream>
  4 #include <cstring>
  5 #include <cctype>
  6 using namespace std;
  7 
  8 // stuct to hold the individual posts
  9 
 10 struct post
 11 {
 12 
 13     int rating;
 14     char comment[];
 15     post * next;
 16 
 17 };
 18 
 19 //class to hold the functions as well as serve as a linked list of topics
 20 
 21 class blog
 22 {
 23 
 24     public:
 25 
 26         blog();
 27         ~blog(); 
 28         int post(char new_topic[], char new_comment[]);
 29         int display(char topic[]);
 30         int display_all();
 31         int rate(char topic[], char keyword[], int rating);
 32         int remove(char topic[], char keyword[]);
 33 
 34     private:
 35 
 36         blog * head;
 37         blog * tail; 
 38         blog * next;
 39         char * topic;
 40         post * next_post;
 41         post * last_post;
 42     
 43 };
```

Comment: If only your compiler was sophisticated enough to output the line number where the error occurs...

Comment: Ah sorry I should have included that.  It says the error is on line 40 & 41.  My bad.

Comment: `post` is the same identifier as your function?

Comment: Ha I suppose that would cause an error.  Thank you

Comment: Also, `char comment[]` is illegal and could trip up the compiler before it gets to `post`. You need a size for the array, or better use `std::string`.

Comment: Unfortunately for the class I'm taking we are not allowed to use strings or statically allocated arrays so I was hoping this method would be a way to allocate the size later.  Thanks for pointing that out though! 

Edit: Could I get away with just saying char * comment and then allocating the size later?

Answer (score 3):

You have a name conflict. In `class blog`, the name `post` refers to two different things. One is `struct post` and the other is a member function.

Rename one of them. Using `::post` or `struct post` to refer to the struct is another possibility, but it's more confusing to the reader

Comment: Alternatives to rename are specifying the struct with namespace :: or adding *struct* keyword, both should work.